# Verifying Touchard's Identity

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

$$C_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n\choose 2k}\cdot C_k\cdot 2^{n-2k}$$
where $C_n$ are the Catalan numbers.

I think we start by diving both sides by $2^n$, but unsure of where to go from there

Comment: Have you tried reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Touchard)?

Comment: ...and a bijective proof follows from [arXiv:math/0406381](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406381), I believe

Comment: i have but im not sure how to progess from here on. ive been trying to find the original proof by touchard but that has not been fruitful, although ive found several things that use n instead of [n/2]

Comment: What do you mean by «progress from here on»? — the linked page contains (a sketch of) a proof. If you don't understand the plan, perhaps you should read some general introduction to generating functions; otherwise — try to follow it.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $2^{-2k}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}=\binom{n/2}{k}\cdot \binom{n/2-1/2}{k}$. So

$$A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}2^n \cdot 2^{-2k}\cdot \binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\cdot\dfrac{1}{k+1}=2^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n/2}{k}\cdot \binom{n/2-1/2}{k}\cdot\dfrac{1}{k+1}$$

Without loss of generality, suppose $n/2 \in \mathbb{N}$. By [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), we have

$$A_n=\dfrac{2^n}{n/2+1} \cdot \binom{n+1/2}{n/2}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}=C_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using the method by Wilf from
*Generatingfunctionology.*

Suppose we are trying to show that
$$C_{n+1} = 2^n \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
{n\choose 2k} C_k 2^{-2k}$$
where $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$ is the $n$-th Catalan number.

Recall the Catalan number recurrence
$$C_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n C_k C_{n-k}$$
which implies for the generating function $C(z)$ of these numbers that
$$\frac{C(z)-1}{z} = C(z)^2$$
which has solutions $$C_{1,2}(z) = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$$
of which the second one is analytic at zero so that
$$C(z) = \frac{1- \sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.$$

Following Wilf we introduce the generating function $D(z)$ where
$$D(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} z^n 2^n 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
{n\choose 2k} C_k 2^{-2k}
= \sum_{k\ge 0} C_k 2^{-2k}
\sum_{n\ge 2k} {n\choose 2k} z^n 2^n
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 0} C_k 2^{-2k}
\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+2k\choose 2k} z^{n+2k} 2^{n+2k}
= \sum_{k\ge 0} C_k z^{2k}
\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+2k\choose 2k} z^n 2^n
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 0} C_k z^{2k} \frac{1}{(1-2z)^{2k+1}}.$$

This gives that
$$D(z) = \frac{1}{1-2z} 
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z^2/(1-2z)^2}}{2z^2/(1-2z)^2}
\\ = \frac{(1-2z)^2}{1-2z} 
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z^2/(1-2z)^2}}{2z^2}
= (1-2z)
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z^2/(1-2z)^2}}{2z^2}
\\= \frac{1-2z-\sqrt{(1-2z)^2-4z^2}}{2z^2}
= \frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z^2}.$$

On the other hand
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} C_{n+1} z^n
= \frac{C(z)-1}{z}
= \frac{1}{z} \left(\frac{1- \sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} -1 \right)
\\ = \frac{1}{z} \left(\frac{1- 2z -\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)
= \frac{1- 2z -\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z^2}.$$

We have equality, QED.