# Closed form as sum and combinatorial of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: analysis, fibonacci-numbers

How can I prove that the Fibonacci numbers that are defined as $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}, \; n \geq 2$ and $F_0=0,\ F_1=1,\ F_2=1$ have the form:

$$F_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1-k}{k}, \; n\ge 2 $$

I am aware of the gen. function that is:
$$\frac{x}{1-x-x^2} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n x^n $$

but I cannot extract the other formula.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: I would have tried that if I could see how it would help here.
The last expression also leads us to the reformation of the gen. function which is after calculation are done:

$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \phi^n -\widehat{\phi}^n \right)$$

Comment: you are trying to prove $$F_n = \sum^{n-1}_{k=0} \binom{n-1-k}{k}$$ correct?

Comment: Yep.. that is the expression I'm trying to prove ...

Comment: How would induction not help?

Comment: Well for once... I suppose that I don't take for granted the values of the Fibonacci sequence. Means that I don't know anything about that.. and I'm trying to express it in a "closed" sum form... using only the recurrance formula these numbers satisfy..or using the gen. function.. which is rather easy to extract.

Comment: "Fibocanni" - made me smile :)

Comment: Oups... My mistake.. !! Sorry.. I'll fix it right now.

Comment: I think the major problem here, is that the relation is false.

Comment: Which relation?? are you refering to?

Comment: Try $n=2$. By recursion, $F_2=1+1=2$, but with your summation, $F_2=\binom{1}{0}+\binom{0}{1}=1$. It's actually only valid for $n>2$, is my point.

Comment: Wow.. !! A.. ok... then ther must be some kind of typo in the book... anyway.. the main question remains.. express the Fibonacci numbers as closed sum form... using either the recursion formula or the gen. function...

Comment: @Demosthene: somtimes FN do start with 0 and hence the expression is correct for $n=2$

Comment: @Alex That doesn't work either, because the relation is true for $n>2$, i.e. is consistent with OP's definition of FN. Let's just edit the question, and make it "prove for $n>2$". Which is true.

Comment: @Demosthene: apologies, I missed this point in the OP and the boundary values.

Comment: @Tolaso Also, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n-1-k}{k}$ is defined only for $n-1-k\ge k$, i.e. when $k$ goes from $0$ to $(n-1)/2$. Since you don't know whether $n$ is odd or even, and you want $(n-1)/2$ to be integer, you can use the IntegerPart function. All that to say that your formula can be written as
$$F_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor (n-1)/2\right\rfloor}\binom{n-1-k}{k}$$ which is equivalent to $$F_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}$$ the latter being a well-known identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one can also be done using complex variables.

Suppose we seek to show that
$$F_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1-k \choose k}.$$
Introduce the integral repesentation
$${n-1-k\choose k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n-1-k}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz.$$
This gives for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{z^k (1+z)^k} \; dz$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z}
\frac{1-1/z^n/(1+z)^n}{1-1/z/(1+z)} \; dz
\\ =\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} (1+z)^{n-1}
\frac{1-1/z^n/(1+z)^n}{z-1/(1+z)} \; dz 
\\ =\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} (1+z)^{n-1}
\frac{1+z-1/z^n/(1+z)^{n-1}}{(1+z)z-1} \; dz 
\\ =\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n-1/z^n}{(1+z)z-1} \; dz.$$

This has two components, the first is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{(1+z)z-1} \; dz$$
which is zero, and the second is
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1/z^n}{(1+z)z-1} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{z}{1-z-z^2} \; dz.$$

Using the generating function this evaluates to 
$$F_n$$ by inspection.

**Observation.** Wilf / *generatingfunctionology* will produce this result as well.

Comment: (+1) I never imagined that this formula would be that "difficult" to show... I like it. But only clarification here... Why the first component is zero.. perhaps I'm over looking something here.

Comment: I believe Wilf / *generatingfunctionology* is the easiest here, it does not use complex variables. The first component is zero because there is no pole inside the circle $|z|=\epsilon.$

Comment: Yes.. sorry.. I had not seen on where you were integrating. Now it seems better that is a circle about the origin and radius $\epsilon$. Hence the contour integral is zero. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: What is WILF / generating functionology? And how would you apply that here?

Comment: There is an example of the technique at this [MSE link I](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792347/) and another example at this [MSE link II](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806590/). The title refers to a classic text on generating functions by H. Wilf which I believe is available for download on his website.

Comment: I thought it was obvious.. but apparently I'm making mistakes here. Using the gen and altering summation and integral I get to a sum that I cannot get the $F_n$ out... meaning that the sum remains.. while it shouldn't .. and I also get a $-1/4\pi^2$.

Could you elaborate on that point?

Comment: I don't quite follow. Maybe you should typeset and post your work (without altering the intent of the question).

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_{\left | z \right |=\epsilon}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}\,dz &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\left | z \right |=\epsilon}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n z^n\,dz \\ 
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\left | z \right |=\epsilon}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{z^n}\,dz\\ 
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n \oint_{\left | z \right |=\epsilon}\frac{dz}{z} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n
\end{aligned}$$

That is what I mean. Am i missing something here?

Comment: It seems you did not distinguish between your summation index and the coefficient extractor. It is not necessary to calculate anything else here, just use [CIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). Good luck, MSE says to conclude.